# Can't POST to server and save

Tags: post, server

I'm trying to do something really simple: just send a string to a server and save it as a txt file. I'm getting nothing at the moment - no txt file - nothing. I'm looking for really simple solutions. Here is what I have:

```
<script>
    function submit()
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.php?d=Hey", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type: text/plain");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<?php
$d = $_POST["d"];
$file = fopen("test.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $d + "\n");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: return type of fwrite() is an int, that signifies the number of byte written.Check if integer is some positive value. This will atleast confirm if something was written.

Comment: check that `$_POST["d"]` is not empty, `test.php?d=Hey`  looks like it will hand over a GET parameter. And are you calling `submit` somewhere?

Comment: So one problem was that the arguments were wrong in setRequestHeader -  it should be:

`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");`

So now it's writing a file ok but the only thing in the file is a single "0" (zero).

@shrinathM - How do I check that? I tried putting it in an echo statement but nothing happens.

@Adder - I'm calling submit by pressing a button. How do I check that `$_POST["d"]` is not empty? echo statements don't seem to do anything.

Comment: You are running asynchronous request. Try setting xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.php?d=Hey", false);

Comment: Setting it to "false" doesn't work and results in the following error:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.